# Infinite Canvas on macOS in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

I'm working on a drawing app for osx. Currently I'm trying to understand how to implement an infinite canvas such as Sketch is providing. I've found https://blog.helftone.com/infinite-nsscrollview/. To use this approach I would have to recenter my content also. The implementation in github seems to use tiles, to make this easier. My problem now is, when I have a simple graph.. e.g. 2 boxes linked with an error, and they are on separate tiles, how would I do this? Also, how would I handle zooming?

Another option I'm aware of is just increasing the contentsize of the NSScrollview.

It seems like there is something missing for me to wrap my head around this :/

Are there any ways I've overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any info about this? I need it also.